# Query Advice needed

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where I manage user login on a machine. Based on the activity type I determine if it is a logon or logoff. I have been asked to generate a report on user login/logout. It works for all the shifts, but doesn't work for Midnight shift.

Sample Table:

```
User_id Activity_code timestamp
1       login         2016-03-28 11:10:00
1       logout        2016-03-28 19:45:00
2       login         2017-02-15 23:00:00
2       logout        2017-02-16 07:00:00
```

If I group by timestamp I get the report properly for user id1, but not for user 2.

```
desc pmevents_bkp

 Name           Null?    Type
 -------------  -------  --------------
 EVENTTYPE      NOT NULL  NUMBER(4)
 USERID                   CHAR(32)
 JOBNUMBER                NUMBER(11)
 TIMESTAMP      NOT NULL  DATE
 SEQUENCENUMBER           NUMBER(8)

 SQL >select * from pmevents_bkp;

 EVENTTYPE USERID                            JOBNUMBER TIMESTAMP SEQUENCENUMBER
---------- -------------------------------- ---------- --------- --------------
       101 JBOND 007                             12345 11-MAR-17          12345
       101 JBOND 007                             12345 12-MAR-17          12345
       101 JBOND 008                              3245 11-MAR-17           3245
       100 JBOND 007                             12345 11-MAR-17           3245

 SQL >select to_char(timestamp, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
    2  userid,
    3  MIN(timestamp) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY eventtype) "Login",
    4  MAX(timestamp) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY eventtype) "Logout"
    5     FROM pmevents_bkp
    6     where  timestamp BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-mar-17','DD-MON-YY') AND TO_DATE('30-mar-17','DD-MON-YY')
    7  and (eventtype = '100'
    8  or eventtype = '101')
    9  group by to_char(timestamp, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),userid;

TO_CHAR(TI USERID                           Login     Logout
---------- -------------------------------- --------- ---------
03/11/2017 JBOND 007                        11-MAR-17 11-MAR-17
03/11/2017 JBOND 008                        11-MAR-17 11-MAR-17
03/12/2017 JBOND 007                        12-MAR-17 12-MAR-17
```

Comment: What is the correct result?  What query have you tried?  Don't be shy.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean that you want to group by the login timestamp, and associate the logout timestamp to the matching login timestamp, no matter whether the logout happens on the next day?

Comment: Can the same user_id log on and out only once? or once a day? or several times per day?

Answer (score 0):

This works regardless if there are multiple login/out per day or if a logout is missing:

```
select *
from 
 (
    select User_id, 

       -- login timestamp
       case when Activity_code = 'login' then timestamp end as Login,

       -- next row's timestamp (only if it's a logout)
       lead(case when Activity_code = 'logout' then timestamp end) 
       over (partition by User_id 
             order by timestamp) as Logout
    from tab
 ) dt
where Logon is not null -- only the login rows
```

Comment: Please find additional details:

Comment: @RookieDBA: Where's the `activity_code` in your example data, it is the `event_type`? And without the time part your example is useless. Nevertheless my approach should work.

Comment: :I tried your query and it works fine for the users who logged on the previous day and logged out the next day. It doesn't give me the result for same day log in and log out.event_type of 100 is log in and 101 is log out. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

@dnoeth:

```
select to_char(timestamp, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
userid,
MIN(timestamp) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY eventtype) "Login",
MAX(timestamp) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY eventtype) "Logout"
FROM formscan.pmevents_bkp
where  timestamp BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-mar-17','DD-MON-YY') AND TO_DATE('30-      
mar-17','DD-MON-YY')
and (eventtype = '100'
or eventtype = '101')
group by to_char(timestamp, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),userid;
```

Comment: This should be part of your question, not an answer. This is your existing query, which is totally different from my answer. Simply change the CASE logic to match `activity_code`, 100 = logon & 101 = logoff?